# React.js Loading animation on page/url change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm new to React and I'm trying to display a loading animation on page/url change (button click) - https://codesandbox.io/s/cthululel-7zmsl?fontsize=14

I've managed to get the animation to work on initial load, but the issue I'm having now is that the loading animation shows when I click on a button, but it also instantly displays the page content (each page is only an h1 tag for testing) and the loading animation doesn't finish. I've cleaned up the sandbox to show the only "working" version I could get to.

Comment: Loaders should be in the "page" level, so each page should decide for itself when to show the loader and when to show anything else (page content)

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the loading component where you have provided route
Try this**

**Home.js**

```
//Apply in each js file
import React from 'react'
import Loading from "../../components/loading/loading";

export default class Home extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          loaded: false,
          done:false
        };
      }
   componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({loaded:true})
        }, 1500);
      }
      }
    render()
    {
        return(
            <div>Home {this.state.loaded ? "" : <Loading />}</div>
        )
    }
}
```